# Obtaining Eigenvalue Expression

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian

Say we have an excitonic system with a creation operator operator:
$$ |\Psi_{ex}\rangle=\sum_{\vec{k}} \phi(\vec{k})c^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}b_{\vec{k}}|GS\rangle$$
And the Hamiltonian of the system reads as:
$$H=\sum_{\vec{k}} E_c(\vec{k})c^\dagger_{\vec{k}}c_{\vec{k}} + \sum_{\vec{k}} E_v(\vec{k})b^\dagger_{\vec{k}}b_{\vec{k}}+\frac{1}{A}\sum_{\vec{k},\vec{k'},\vec{q}}V(\vec{q})c^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{q}}b^\dagger_{\vec{k'}-\vec{q}}c_{\vec{k}}b_{\vec{k}} $$
Now say we want to obtain the eigenvalue expression for this. One paper I have seen used the Heisenberg equation of motion with the polarization operator to obtain the eigenvalue expression. Which then reads as:
$$P(t)=\langle c^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}(t)b_{\vec{k}}(t) \rangle$$

My question is how can the equation of motion be used here as a valid way to obtain the exciton energy of this system.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the exciton energy, you can use the Heisenberg equation of motion for the operators involved (for simplicity starting from here I'll denote the creation and annihilation operators as $C^\dagger$ and $B$ respectively).

The Heisenberg equation of motion for an operator $O$ is given by:
$$
\frac{dO}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H, O]
$$

For the operators $C^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}(t)$ and $B_{\vec{k}}(t)$, the equation of motion becomes:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}C^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}(t) = \frac{i}{\hbar}[H,C^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}(t)] $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}B_{\vec{k}}(t) =  \frac{i}{\hbar}[H,B_{\vec{k}}(t)] $$

Now, you can use these equations of motion to evaluate the time derivative of the polarization operator $P(t)$:

$$
\frac{dP}{dt} = \frac{i}{\hbar}\langle[H, C^\dagger_{\vec{k}+\vec{Q}}(t)B_{\vec{k}}(t)]\rangle 
$$

Expanding the commutator and using the Hamiltonian $H$, you'll obtain terms involving the creation and annihilation operators. Then, you can evaluate the expectation value $\langle \cdots \rangle$ using the initial state $|\Psi_{ex}\rangle$.

By solving the resulting equations or employing some approximation methods, you can derive an expression for the exciton energy in terms of the system parameters and the interaction potential $V(\vec{q})$.